# Laravel phpunit testing needs access to API Service for user validation

Tags: laravel, api, service, phpunit

I am working on a Laravel project that is accessing an API for all backend data storage.  This includes the user authentication.

I have an API Service as well as a API Service Provider that substantiates the Service and then feeds that service to all of the pages with the request var.

I figured it was easier just to substantiate the API Service in the Test Class so that's what I am doing but I am running into issues with the sessions.

Here is what I have so far:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Services\ApiService;

class LoginTest extends TestCase
{
    private $apiService;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->withSession(['user' => '', 'auth_token' => '']);
        $url = env('API_URL');
        $this->$apiService = new ApiService($url);
    }
```

I am getting this error:
Call to a member function isStarted() on null.

Is there a better way to call an API Service that relies on session variables for testing?

Answer (score 0):

How we ended up doing this:

We changed my constructor to a parent::SetUp to call the API Service

```
public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        
        $url = env('API_URL');
        $this->ApiService = new ApiService($url);
    }
```

Then in tests/TestCase we called post login routing passing the hard coded test username and password info.

```
public function login()
    {
        $this->post("/login", ['email' => 'admin@big-api.test', 'password' => 'ThisUserWillBeDeleted']);
    }
```

Now I just call the login function on each of my tests cases where I need to be logged in through the API in order to access a page.

This ended up being a lot simpler than I thought but it took a bit to get there.  Hope this is helpful for someone else.